# paths should be a straight line

Tags: javascript, d3.js, directed-acyclic-graphs

i was trying to get a flow diagram with straight path lines, however i see a non -linear straight lines , instead the path should be a straight line emanating from the end of rectangular node and ending at the another node.

should look this
http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/examples/unix.html

now looks like this(Here's an example of the issue )
http://jsfiddle.net/eM6jU/204/

```
 var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
                        .x(function (d)
                        { return d.x; })
                        .y(function (d)
                        { return d.y; })
                        .interpolate("linear");
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed this function and it is working as expected 
http://jsfiddle.net/eM6jU/206/

```
 var routeEdges = function () {
                                d3cola.prepareEdgeRouting();
                                link.attr("d", function (d) {
                                    return lineFunction(d3cola.routeEdge(d
                                            // show visibility graph
                                            //, function (g) {
                                            //    if (d.source.id === 10 && d.target.id === 11) {
                                            //    g.E.forEach(function (e) {
                                            //        vis.append("line").attr("x1", e.source.p.x).attr("y1", e.source.p.y)
                                            //            .attr("x2", e.target.p.x).attr("y2", e.target.p.y)
                                            //            .attr("stroke", "green");
                                            //    });
                                            //    }
                                            //}
                                    ));
                                });}
```